# Unable to add rows in embedded list

Tags: servicenow

I have access to cmdb table  but how I can add a row here in embedded list like this(screenshot)

For some records it is allowing to add and for some records it is not.

Please help me out.....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since this is an embedded list, these are normally adjusted by ACLs or Client Scripts. Can you look to see if there are any that apply to this?

Comment: @Kirk thanks for responding, I got the solution on the community https://community.servicenow.com/thread/262945